# How to minify scripts from web accessible resources?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, vite

I have browser extension (TypeScript) that build via [Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite) with [plugin CRXJS](https://crxjs.dev/vite-plugin). After build, created folder with minified scripts, but skipped scripts from `manifest.web_accessible_resources` (used for injection to web page).

What I need to do in order to minify file `src/injection.js` when building? At the moment the file just copy-paste to output folder.

```
// manifest.ts
import { defineManifest } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'

export default defineManifest({
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": [
        "https://*.example.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/content/content.ts"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "src/popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "src/background/background.ts"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "assets/icons/icon48.png",
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.example.com/*"
      ],
      "resources": [
        "src/injection.js",
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true,
    }
  ],
})
```

```
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import path from 'path'
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess'
import manifest from './src/manifest';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const production = mode === 'production'

  return {
    build: {
      minify: true,
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: 'build',
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          },
        },
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      crx({ manifest }),
      svelte({
        compilerOptions: {
          dev: !production,
        },
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
      }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 
      },
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If add filepaths to `build.rollupOptions.input`, `Vite` will minify them too.

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import path from 'path'
import manifest from './src/manifest';

const jsFilesToInclude = manifest.web_accessible_resources
  .map(item => item.resources.filter(path => path.endsWith('.js')))
  .flat(1)
  .map(path => 'public/' + path)

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const production = mode === 'production'

  return {
    build: {
      minify: true,
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: 'build',
      rollupOptions: {
        input: jsFilesToInclude,
        output: {
            return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          },
        },
      }
    }
  }
})
```